# CKEditor: Check if elements path contains element with special attribute and value

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a CKEditor plugin and want to check, if the element at the current cursor position has a parent element with a special attribute and value.

I know, that I can check the path with `editor.elementsPath().contains('tagname')` but I not only want to check for the tagname but also for an attribute and an attributes value like `tagname[attribute=value]`. But it looks like this spelling does not work with the `contains()`function.

Any idea how to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass evaluator function as a parameter of [`editor.elementPath().contains()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.elementPath-method-contains):

```
editor.elementPath().contains( function( element ) {        
    if ( element.is( 'tagname' ) && element.getAttribute( 'attribute' ) == 'value' )
        return true;
} ); // -> element or null
```